Does inheritance break encapsulation even if its members are private?
I was reading the book "Design Patterns. Elements of Reusable Object-Oriented Software" and find this statement very interesting:

Because inheritance exposes a subclass to details of its parent's implementation, it's often said that "inheritance breaks encapsulation".

Would this be true even if all the members of a superclass are private? With the exception of its interface, of course.
Another question: if inheritance would break encapsulation anyway, even if the subclass could only see the interface of its superclass, how would alternative methods to inheritance, like delegation, not break it?

Indeed, OO was born for encapsulation, plain and simple: inheritance and polymorphisms are extensions introduced later by Stroustrup.  But I have no specific references for the details of that story/progressions, should be possible to find it in some good introductions to C++.
